# json parsing in haskell

Tags: json, haskell, haskell-platform

I'm trying to parse JSON data in haskell. Having gone through a slew of websites, this is the furthest I have been able to get to.

```
data Address = Address { house :: Integer, street :: String, city :: String, state :: String, zip :: Integer } deriving (Show)
data Person = Person { name :: String, age :: Integer, address :: Address } deriving (Show)

getName :: Person -> String
getName (Person n _ _) = n

getAddress :: Person -> Address
getAddress (Person _ _ a) = a

getState :: Address -> String
getState (Address _ _ _ s _) = s
```

I write that in a file ex.hs and load it in ghci -->

```
Prelude> import Text.JSON
Prelude Text.JSON> :load ex
Main Text.JSON> let aa = "{\"name\": \"some body\", \"age\" : 23, \"address\" : {\"house\" : 285, \"street\" : \"7th Ave.\", \"city\" : \"New York\", \"state\" : \"New York\", \"zip\" : 10001}}"
...> decode aa :: Result JSValue
```

It returns

```
Ok (JSObject (JSONObject {fromJSObject = [("name",JSString (JSONString {fromJSString = "some body"})),("age",JSRational False (23 % 1)),("address",JSObject (JSONObject {fromJSObject = [("house",JSRational False (285 % 1)),("street",JSString (JSONString {fromJSString = "7th Ave."})),("city",JSString (JSONString {fromJSString = "New York"})),("state",JSString (JSONString {fromJSString = "New York"})),("zip",JSRational False (10001 % 1))]}))]}))
```

Needless to say, it seems pretty verbose (and frightening). I tried doing

```
...> decode aa :: Result Person
```

and it gave me an error. How do I go about populating an instance of the Person datastructure from this json string? For example, what should I do to get the state of the person in the JSON string...

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The problem is that `Text.JSON` does not know how to convert `JSON` data to
your `Person` data type. To do this, you need to either make `Person` and
instance of the `JSON` typeclass, or your can use `Text.JSON.Generic` and the
`DeriveDataTypeable` extension to do the work for you.

## Generics

The `Text.JSON.Generic` method will read the `JSON` structure based on the
structure of your data type.

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveDataTypeable #-}
import           Text.JSON.Generic

data Address = Address
    { house  :: Integer
    , street :: String
    , city   :: String
    , state  :: String
    , zip    :: Integer
    } deriving (Show, Data, Typeable)

data Person = Person
    { name    :: String
    , age     :: Integer
    , address :: Address
    } deriving (Show, Data, Typeable)

aa :: String
aa = "{\"name\": \"some body\", \"age\" : 23, \"address\" : {\"house\" : 285, \"street\" : \"7th Ave.\", \"city\" : \"New York\", \"state\" : \"New York\", \"zip\" : 10001}}"

main = print (decodeJSON aa :: Person)
```

This method works really well as long as you don't mind matching the names of the fields
in your data structure to your `JSON` format.

As an aside, you don't need to write functions like `getName`, `getAddress`,
and `getState`. The names of the field in your record type are accesor
functions.

```
∀ x. x ⊦ :t house
house :: Address -> Integer
∀ x. x ⊦ :t address
address :: Person -> Address
```

## JSON Instance

Alternatively, you could take the high road and implement your own instance of
the `JSON` class.

```
import           Control.Applicative
import           Control.Monad
import           Text.JSON

data Address = Address
    { house  :: Integer
    , street :: String
    , city   :: String
    , state  :: String
    -- Renamed so as not to conflict with zip from Prelude
    , zipC   :: Integer
    } deriving (Show)

data Person = Person
    { name    :: String
    , age     :: Integer
    , address :: Address
    } deriving (Show)

aa :: String
aa = "{\"name\": \"some body\", \"age\" : 23, \"address\" : {\"house\" : 285, \"street\" : \"7th Ave.\", \"city\" : \"New York\", \"state\" : \"New York\", \"zip\" : 10001}}"

-- For convenience
(!) :: (JSON a) => JSObject JSValue -> String -> Result a
(!) = flip valFromObj

instance JSON Address where
    -- Keep the compiler quiet
    showJSON = undefined

    readJSON (JSObject obj) =
        Address        <$>
        obj ! "house"  <*>
        obj ! "street" <*>
        obj ! "city"   <*>
        obj ! "state"  <*>
        obj ! "zip"
    readJSON _ = mzero

instance JSON Person where
    -- Keep the compiler quiet
    showJSON = undefined

    readJSON (JSObject obj) =
        Person       <$>
        obj ! "name" <*>
        obj ! "age"  <*>
        obj ! "address"
    readJSON _ = mzero

main = print (decode aa :: Result Person)
```

This takes advantage of the fact that the `Result` type is an `Applicative` to easily
chain together queries on the `JSObject` value.

This is a little more work, but it gives you more control of the structure of
the `JSON` if you have to deal with `JSON` that will cause style guideline
violations due to weird field names.

Comment: Maybe you should also give an example of creating an instance of JSON since you mentioned it as an alternative.

Comment: Very useful information. I have a question. Apart from `Text.JSON.Generic` (which package does it come from?), I've also found https://hackage.haskell.org/package/generic-aeson similarly employing the Generics machinery to make JSON instances of Haskell data. What are the differences between these two packages?

Comment: [bergmark](https://github.com/silkapp/generic-aeson/issues/7): "note that `Text.JSON` is from the `json` package which is old and not commonly used anymore."

Comment: The `json` package: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/json 
or you can use in the terminal:
`cabal install json`

Answer (score 14):

Maybe a bit late in the game, but since this is the first page google returns I'll give it a go.

[Aeson](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson) is the defacto standard these days so that's the library everybody uses. The [Aeson TH](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-0.10.0.0/docs/Data-Aeson-TH.html) package offers some nice functionality for automatically generating the necessary functions for your custom data types.

Basically you create your data types that correspond to the json data and then let aeson do the magic.

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings,TemplateHaskell #-}
import Data.Aeson
import Data.Aeson.TH
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as BL

data Address = Address
    { house  :: Integer
    , street :: String
    , city   :: String
    , state  :: Maybe String
    , zip    :: Integer
    } deriving (Show, Eq)

data Person = Person
    { name    :: String
    , age     :: Integer
    , address :: Address
    } deriving (Show, Eq)

$(deriveJSON defaultOptions ''Address)
$(deriveJSON defaultOptions ''Person)

aa :: BL.ByteString
aa = "{\"name\": \"some body\", \"age\" : 23, \"address\" : {\"house\" : 285, \"street\" : \"7th Ave.\", \"city\" : \"New York\", \"state\" : \"New York\", \"zip\" : 10001}}"

main = print (decode aa :: Maybe Person)
```

You can even have optional fields with the `Maybe` datatype.

Comment: Aeson has to link a lot more libraries than the `json` package

Answer (score 1):

Since the answers are a bit old and the Haskell ecosystem has improved a little since, let me mention that [`aeson`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson) with [`generic-aeson`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/generic-aeson) seems to be the best option so far:

```
{-# language DeriveGeneric #-}

import GHC.Generics (Generic)
import Generics.Generic.Aeson

data Terms = Terms
  { termsEnd :: Day
  , termsStart :: Day
  , termsType :: Text
  , termsParty :: Text
  , termsState :: Text
  }
  deriving (Generic, Show, Eq)

stripSettings :: Settings
stripSettings = defaultSettings {stripPrefix = Just "terms"}

instance FromJSON Terms where parseJSON = gparseJsonWithSettings stripSettings
```

I started off using [Chris Penner's JSON to Haskell tool](http://json-to-haskell.chrispenner.ca/) (which is awesome on its own btw) and then added the Generics instances to make it work without boilerplate.

I think this is the best solution so far because it allows you to decode JSON fields even when they use **Haskell keywords** (like `type`, in my example) via `gparseJsonWithSettings` and **automatic parsing of dates** to `Data.Time.Calendar.Day` just works seamlessly!!