# json parsing in haskell part 2 - Non-exhaustive patterns in lambda

Tags: json, lambda, haskell

This is actually in continuation of the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17844223/1045053) I asked a few days back. I took the applicative functors route and made my own instances.

I need to parse a huge number of json statements all in a file, one line after the other. An example json statement is something like this -

```
{"question_text": "How can NBC defend tape delaying the Olympics when everyone has
Twitter?", "context_topic": {"followers": 21, "name": "NBC Coverage of the London
Olympics (July & August 2012)"}, "topics": [{"followers": 2705,
"name": "NBC"},{"followers": 21, "name": "NBC Coverage of the London 
Olympics (July & August 2012)"},
{"followers": 17828, "name": "Olympic Games"},
{"followers": 11955, "name": "2012 Summer Olympics in London"}], 
"question_key": "AAEAABORnPCiXO94q0oSDqfCuMJ2jh0ThsH2dHy4ATgigZ5J",
"__ans__": true, "anonymous": false}
```

*sorry for the json formatting. It got bad*

I have about 10000 such json statements and I need to parse them. The code I have written is
something like this -

```
parseToRecord :: B.ByteString -> Question
parseToRecord bstr = (\(Ok x) -> x) decodedObj where decodedObj = decode (B.unpack bstr) :: Result Question

main :: IO()
main = do
  -- my first line in the file tells how many json statements
  -- are there followed by a lot of other irrelevant info...
  ts <- B.getContents >>= return . fst . fromJust . B.readInteger . head . B.lines
  json_text <- B.getContents >>= return . tail . B.lines
  let training_data = take (fromIntegral ts) json_text
  let questions = map parseToRecord training_data
  print $ questions !! 8922
```

This code gives me a runtime error `Non-exhaustive patterns in lambda`. The error references to `\(Ok x) -> x` in the code. By hit and trial, I came to the conclusion that the program works ok till the 8921th index and fails on the 8922th iteration.

I checked the corresponding json statement and tried to parse it standalone by calling the function on it and it works. However, it doesn't work when I call *map*. I don't really understand what is going on. Having learnt a little bit of haskell in "learn haskell for a great good", I wanted to dive into a real world programming project but seem to have got stuck here.

EDIT :: complete code is as follows

```
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -O2 -optc-O2 #-}
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -fno-warn-incomplete-uni-patterns #-}
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as B
import Data.Maybe
import NLP.Tokenize

import           Control.Applicative
import           Control.Monad
import           Text.JSON

data Topic = Topic
  { followers :: Integer,
    name :: String
  } deriving (Show)

data Question = Question
  { question_text :: String,
    context_topic :: Topic,
    topics :: [Topic],
    question_key :: String,
    __ans__ :: Bool,
    anonymous :: Bool
  } deriving (Show)

(!) :: (JSON a) => JSObject JSValue -> String -> Result a
(!) = flip valFromObj

instance JSON Topic where
  -- Keep the compiler quiet
  showJSON = undefined

  readJSON (JSObject obj) =
    Topic       <$>
    obj ! "followers" <*>
    obj ! "name"
  readJSON _ = mzero

instance JSON Question where
  -- Keep the compiler quiet
  showJSON = undefined

  readJSON (JSObject obj) =
    Question      <$>
    obj ! "question_text"   <*>
    obj ! "context_topic" <*>
    obj ! "topics" <*>
    obj ! "question_key" <*>
    obj ! "__ans__" <*>
    obj ! "anonymous"
  readJSON _ = mzero

isAnswered (Question _ _ _ _ status _) = status
isAnonymous (Question _ _ _ _ _ status) = status

parseToRecord :: B.ByteString -> Question
parseToRecord bstr = handle decodedObj
                        where handle (Ok k)     = k
                              handle (Error e)  = error (e ++ "\n" ++ show bstr)
                              decodedObj = decode (B.unpack bstr) :: Result Question
--parseToRecord bstr = (\(Ok x) -> x) decodedObj where decodedObj = decode (B.unpack bstr) :: Result Question

main :: IO()
main = do
  ts <- B.getContents >>= return . fst . fromJust . B.readInteger . head . B.lines
  json_text <- B.getContents >>= return . tail . B.lines
  let training_data = take (fromIntegral ts) json_text
  let questions = map parseToRecord training_data
  let correlation = foldr (\x acc -> if (isAnonymous x == isAnswered x) then (fst acc + 1, snd acc + 1) else (fst acc, snd acc + 1)) (0,0) questions
  print $ fst correlation
```

here's the [data](http://hr-testcases.s3.amazonaws.com/688/sample.zip) which can be given as input to the executable. I'm using ghc 7.6.3. If the program name is ans.hs, I followed these steps.

```
$ ghc --make ans.hs
$ ./ans < path/to/the/file/sample/answered_data_10k.in
```

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lambda function `(\(Ok x) -> x)` is partial in that it will only be able to match objects that were successfully decoded. If you are experiencing this, it indicates that your `JSON` parser is failing to parse a record, for some reason.

Making the `parseToRecord` function more informative would help you find the error. Try actually reporting the error, rather than reporting a failed pattern match.

```
parseToRecord :: B.ByteString -> Question
parseToRecord bstr = handle decodedObj 
    where handle (Ok k)    = k
          handle (Error e) = error e
          decodedObj = decode (B.unpack bstr) :: Result Question
```

If you want more help, it might be useful to include the parser code.

## Update

Based on your code and sample `JSON`, it looks like your code is first failing
when it encounters a `null` in the `context_topic` field of your `JSON`.
Your current code cannot handle a `null`, so it fails to parse. My fix would
be something like the following, but you could come up with other ways to
handle it.

```
data Nullable a = Null
                | Full a
    deriving (Show)

instance JSON a => JSON (Nullable a) where
    showJSON Null     = JSNull
    showJSON (Full a) = showJSON a

    readJSON JSNull   = Ok Null
    readJSON c        = Full `fmap` readJSON c

data Question = Question
  { question_text :: String,
    context_topic :: Nullable Topic,
    topics :: [Topic],
    question_key :: String,
    __ans__ :: Bool,
    anonymous :: Bool
  } deriving (Show)
```

It also seems to fail on line 9002, where there is a naked value of "1000" on
that line, and it seems that several `JSON` values after that line lack the
`'__ans__'` field.

Comment: Maybe you should complete the code in your post, so one can test it. Furthermore, it could helpful to know which part of the bytestring does not parse. So instead of just printing the error message, you could print s.th. like: `error (e ++ "\n" ++ show bstr)`

Comment: Thanks for looking into the problem. I have completed the code for you to test. Also, here's the link to the json file. (the file with .in type in the zip file) - http://hr-testcases.s3.amazonaws.com/688/sample.zip

Comment: yes, I seemed to have missed the null values in the json file. Thanks for pointing it out and also suggesting the change in the code.

Answer (score 0):

I would have suggestion to use `Maybe` in order to parse the null values:

```
data Question = Question
  { question_text :: String
  , context_topic :: Maybe Topic
  , topics :: [Topic]
  , question_key :: String
  , __ans__ :: Bool
  , anonymous :: Bool
  } deriving (Show)
```

And then change the `readJSON` function as follows (in addition, the missing **ans**-fields can be fixed by returning `False` on an unsuccessful parsing attempt):

```
instance JSON Question where
  -- Keep the compiler quiet
  showJSON = undefined

  readJSON (JSObject obj) = Question <$>
    obj ! "question_text"   <*>
    (fmap Just (obj ! "context_topic") <|> return Nothing) <*>
    obj ! "topics" <*>
    obj ! "question_key" <*>
    (obj ! "__ans__" <|> return False) <*>
    obj ! "anonymous"
  readJSON _ = mzero
```

After getting rid of the `1000` in line 9000-something (like sabauma mentioned), I got `4358` as result. So maybe these slight changes are enough?

Comment: You can make your `context_topic` line  little more readable by taking advantage of the fact that `m >>= return . f == fmap f m`. I would have went with using `Maybe`, but its `JSON` instance was not what I would have expected (i.e. not how I implemented it for `Nullable`).

Comment: Ah, thanks for that hint.
I wasn't sure if it behaves as wished either, but the whole data was parsed successfully. So I guess that it worked quite well.