# Adding maybeness to a Haskell data type (with record syntax)

Tags: haskell, option-type

Looking at an answer to this question:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/34164251/1052117

I see that it defines a data type that is used to parse a JSON object.

```
data Address = Address
    { house  :: Integer
    , street :: String
    , city   :: String
    , state  :: Maybe String
    , zip    :: String -- here I change the original, zip codes are strings, they have leading zeros.
    } deriving (Show, Eq)

$(deriveJSON defaultOptions ''Address)
```

This is helpful, but I wonder: How could I change the Address data type to have all json fields be nullable?  Specifically I see a Maybe before the state field, but I'm imagining a larger data structure where it would  be tedious to modify all of the fields to Maybe fields.  For example, while I /could/ re-write above as:

```
data Address = Address
    { house  :: Maybe Integer
    , street :: Maybe String
    , city   :: Maybe String
    , state  :: Maybe String
    , zip    :: Maybe String
    } deriving (Show, Eq)
```

What function could I apply to the Address data type /in code/ to achieve this same result without rewriting all the code and manually inserting the Maybes?

Comment: 1. https://www.benjamin.pizza/posts/2017-12-15-functor-functors.html 
2. http://reasonablypolymorphic.com/blog/higher-kinded-data/

Answer (score 5):

As is discussed in the comments, using a functor-functor would work for this with just very small changes to the original data type.

If you start out with

```
data Address = Address
    { house  :: Integer
    , street :: String
    , city   :: String
    , state  :: Maybe String
    , zip    :: String
    } deriving (Show, Eq)
```

then it is equivalent to

```
import Data.Functor.Identity

data AddressF f = Address
  { house  :: f Integer 
  , street :: f String
  , city   :: f String
  , state  :: Maybe String
  , zip    :: f String 
  } deriving (Show, Eq)

type Address = AddressF Identity
```

and then you can get the second one by writing

```
type Address' = AddressF Maybe
```

To get back to the original definition, you can write

```
toOriginal (AddressF (Identity house) (Identity street) (Identity city) mbState (Identity zip)) = Address house street city mbState zip
```

Comment: Can AddressF be used like the original Address type?  eg, what's the identity f that would reproduce the original?

Comment: You can write functions on AddressF just like you would anything else, like you could have something `:: AddressF f -> f (String, Integer)` but it would always be polymorphic over the functor. 

Editing to be more clear about going between the original and the Address I provided.

Answer (score 2):

> achieve this same result without rewriting all the code and manually
>   inserting the Maybes

To avoid intrusive changes to the record type, we can work with another type that is *derived* from the record one by analyzing its structure, something which requires relatively advanced generic and type-level programming. This answer uses the [generics-sop](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/generics-sop) package.

Some required pragmas and imports:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, TypeFamilies, FlexibleInstances, UndecidableInstances, 
             ScopedTypeVariables, TypeApplications, TypeOperators, 
             DeriveGeneric, StandaloneDeriving, MultiParamTypeClasses,
             FunctionalDependencies, AllowAmbiguousTypes, FlexibleContexts #-}
import           Data.Kind (Type)
import           Data.Type.Equality (type (==))
import           GHC.TypeLits
import qualified GHC.Generics as GHC
import           Generics.SOP -- from package "generics-sop"
import qualified Generics.SOP.Type.Metadata as M
```

This newtype represents an [n-ary product](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/generics-sop-0.4.0.1/docs/Generics-SOP.html#t:NP) of field values derived from a record, each wrapped in a functor `f`. The type-level list `ns` of field [names](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/GHC-TypeLits.html#t:Symbol) is kept as a [phantom type variable](https://wiki.haskell.org/Phantom_type):

```
newtype Wrapped f (ns :: [Symbol]) (xs :: [Type]) = Wrapped { unwrap :: NP f xs }

deriving instance All (Generics.SOP.Compose Show f) xs => Show (Wrapped f ns xs)

type family FieldNamesOf (a :: M.DatatypeInfo) :: [Symbol] where
    FieldNamesOf ('M.ADT moduleName datatypeName '[ 'M.Record constructorName fields ]) = 
        ExtractFieldNames fields

type family ExtractFieldNames (a :: [M.FieldInfo]) :: [Symbol] where
    ExtractFieldNames '[] = '[]
    ExtractFieldNames (('M.FieldInfo n) ': xs) = n ': ExtractFieldNames xs

fromRecord :: forall r ns xs.  (IsProductType r xs, 
                                HasDatatypeInfo r, 
                                FieldNamesOf (DatatypeInfoOf r) ~ ns)
           => r 
           -> Wrapped I ns xs 
fromRecord r = let (SOP (Z np)) = from r in Wrapped np

toRecord :: forall r ns xs.  (IsProductType r xs, 
                              HasDatatypeInfo r, 
                              FieldNamesOf (DatatypeInfoOf r) ~ ns)
         => Wrapped I ns xs 
         -> r
toRecord (Wrapped np) = to (SOP (Z np))
```

If we don't need to keep the field names around, the newtype becomes superfluous, and it's better to work directly with the n-ary product [NP](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/generics-sop-0.4.0.1/docs/Generics-SOP.html#t:NP), manipulating it with the [rich set of functions](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/sop-core-0.4.0.0/docs/Data-SOP-NP.html) provided by generics-sop.

But if we do want to maintain the ability to select fields by name, then we need to define a function on the newtype, supported by a pair typeclasses:

```
getWrappedField :: forall n f ns xs x. HasField ns n xs x => Wrapped f ns xs -> f x
getWrappedField (Wrapped np) = getHasField @ns @n np  

class HasField (ns :: [Symbol]) (n :: Symbol) 
               (xs :: [Type])   (x :: Type)   | ns n xs -> x where 
    getHasField :: NP f xs -> f x 

instance ((e == n) ~ flag, HasField' flag (e : ns) n xs x) => HasField (e : ns) n xs x where
    getHasField = getHasField' @flag @(e : ns) @n

class HasField' (flag :: Bool) 
                (ns :: [Symbol]) (n :: Symbol) 
                (xs :: [Type]) (x :: Type)     | ns n xs -> x where 
    getHasField' :: NP f xs -> f x 

instance HasField' True (n : ns) n (x : xs) x where
    getHasField' (v :* _) = v

instance HasField ns n xs x => HasField' False (nz : ns) n (xz : xs) x where
    getHasField' (_ :* rest) = getHasField @ns @n rest
```

Given this example record which derives the [necessary](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/GHC-Generics.html#t:Generic) [supporting](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/generics-sop-0.4.0.1/docs/Generics-SOP.html#t:Generic) [typeclasses](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/generics-sop-0.4.0.1/docs/Generics-SOP.html#t:HasDatatypeInfo):

```
data Person = Person { name :: String, age :: Int } deriving (Show, GHC.Generic)
instance Generic Person
instance HasDatatypeInfo Person
```

We can construct its generalized representation (where all the fields are initially wrapped in the identity functor [I](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/generics-sop-0.4.0.1/docs/Generics-SOP.html#t:I)) and then get one of the fields, like this:

```
ghci> getWrappedField @"age" (fromRecord (Person "Jimmy" 25))
I 25
```

The name of the field is passed as a type-level `Symbol`, using [type application](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html?highlight=typeapplications#extension-TypeApplications).

Comment: There's a large amount of overlap between this and what the `records-sop` package does.

Comment: @kosmikus Ah, I had looked at `records-sop` but somehow missed the `IsElemOf` typeclass! As an outgrowth of this answer, I'm working on a package that defines records and variants indexed by a type-level rose tree https://github.com/danidiaz/red-black-record It piggybacks on `sop-core` and uses a technique like the one in `records-sop` to avoid overlapping instances.